# Simulate rsync - find how much data needs to be transferred without modifying files

Tags: rsync

I'm looking to replicate some of my backups across storage and am trying to investigate how to do that with minimal I/O and network traffic. This has some bearing on what hardware I need to go out and buy - so as yet I can't experiment by carrying out actual transfers. I do however have a series of full backups on the primary storage which I can compare (but not overwrite).

Is there a way to run rsync such that it will report the amount of data it *would* have transfered without actually writing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

```
  -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
      --stats                 give some file-transfer stats
```